# Unable parse JSON String using Javascript

Tags: javascript, community, salesforce1-app, javascript-remoting

I am facing issue parsing JSON String on the front-end. The parameter result represents a String

```
function handleresult (result,event){
var newResult  = JSON.stringify(result);
var temp = JSON.parse(newResult);
}
```

So now the temp variable contains a JSON object which looks like this with escape quotes and ampersand characters, 
{& quot ;message& quot;:& quot;Cannot find entity by key: 'A0000002'.",& quot;errorCode& quot;:& quot;53610040& quot;}.

But what i want is something like this so that i can parse the key/value pair inside the JSON:
{"message":"Cannot find entity by key: 'A0000002'.","errorCode":"53610040"}.

I have tried using the JSON.replace(/& quote ;/g,'"') method, but it does not replace the " character.

Please if someone can tell me what can i do to fix this problem?

Note : There is "/&  quot ; " which i want to replace

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `JSON.stringify()` - it expects a `JSON` object, not a result string.
Just call `JSON.parse()` Like so:

```
function handleresult (result,event){
var newResult  = JSON.parse(result);
```

Docs are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)